Getting 500 Internal Server Error when registering GitLab runner with some specific tag
I am encountering a "500 Internal Server Error" when attempting to register a GitLab runner using some tag like regression-runner-rocky. Strangely, registration is successful when using a different tags like regression-runner-centos , performance-test-runner
Here is the command I'm using to register the runner with the problematic tag:
curl --request POST --url "https://gitlab.xyz.com/api/v4/user/runners" --data "runner_type=project_type" --data "project_id=${CI_PROJECT_ID}"  --data "run_untagged=false" --data "description=${RUNNER_DESCRIPTION}" --data "tag_list=regression-runner-rocky" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}"  > runner.json

And here is the command that successfully registers the runner with a different tag (`regression-runner-centos`):
- curl --request POST --url "https://gitlab.xyz.com/api/v4/user/runners" --data "runner_type=project_type" --data "project_id=${CI_PROJECT_ID}"  --data "run_untagged=false" --data "description=${RUNNER_DESCRIPTION}" --data "tag_list=regression-runner-centos" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}"  > runner.json
- export TF_VAR_gitlab_auth_token=$(grep -Po "glrt-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+" runner.json)

FYI: The exported TF_VAR_gitlab_auth_token is used in a Terraform script as follows:
user_data = templatefile("install-gitlab-runner.tftpl", { registration_token = var.gitlab_auth_token })

the runner is registered on an EC2 instance using the following command:
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "https://gitlab.xyz.com/"  --token "${registration_token}" --executor "shell"

What I've Tried:

Double-checked the correctness of the command syntax and variables.

Confirmed that the GITLAB_API_TOKEN and CI_PROJECT_ID variables are correct.

Verified that the RUNNER_DESCRIPTION variable is properly set.

Attempted to register the runner with the problematic tag multiple times, but consistently received a 500 Internal Server Error.


I expected this command to behave similarly to the one that successfully registered the runner with a different tag (regression-runner-centos), but instead, it consistently resulted in a "500 Internal Server Error."
Please review my question and provide any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and what is the reason for this behavior. Thank you!
